Not getting authenticated user in middleware with OpenIdConnect in ASP.NET Core 8
I have issues with my ASP.NET Core application that it is trying to retrieve user claims in the middleware.
This is my program cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())    
     builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets<Program>();

var openIddictSettings = new OpenIddictSettings();
builder.Configuration.GetSection("OpenIddict").Bind(openIddictSettings);

// Add services to the container.
var origins = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Cors:Origins").Get<string[]>();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(config =>
    {
        config.AllowAnyHeader();
        config.AllowAnyMethod();
        config.AllowCredentials();
        config.WithOrigins(origins)
        .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
    });
});

builder.Services.AddNNTCupBusiness(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>>();

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;

    var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var policy = policyBuilder.Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    options.ModelValidatorProviders.Clear();
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
{
    x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    x.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JsonStringConverter());
    x.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    x.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ";
})
.AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
}
);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument();

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        // Note: the validation handler uses OpenID Connect discovery
        // to retrieve the address of the introspection endpoint.
        options.SetIssuer(openIddictSettings.StsUrl);
        options.AddAudiences(openIddictSettings.Audience);

        // Configure the validation handler to use introspection and register the client
        // credentials used when communicating with the remote introspection endpoint.
        options.SetClientId(openIddictSettings.ApiClientId);

        // Register the System.Net.Http integration.
        options.UseSystemNetHttp();

        // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // When targeting OpenIddict 3.0, OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults
    // must be used instead of OpenIddictValidationDefaults.
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "NNT CUP Api", Version = "v1" });
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "OAuth2.0 Auth Code with PKCE",
        Name = "oauth2",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(openIddictSettings.StsUrl + "/connect/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri(openIddictSettings.StsUrl + "/connect/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { openIddictSettings.SwaggerScope, "read the api" }
                    }
            }
        }
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
                },
                new[] { openIddictSettings.SwaggerScope }
            }
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var cultureService = app.Services.GetService<ICultureService>();
    var cultureCodes = cultureService.GetAll().Result.Select(x => x.CultureCode).ToArray();

    options.AddSupportedCultures(cultureCodes);
    options.AddSupportedUICultures(cultureCodes);
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OpenIddict_OAuth_CUS_API v1");
        options.OAuthClientId(openIddictSettings.SwaggerClientId);
        options.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        options.OAuthUsePkce();
    });
}

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
        && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
});

app.UseMiddleware<ApplicationUserCustomerValidationMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<ExportToExcelMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

And my middleware is looking like this:
public class ApplicationUserCustomerValidationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) 
{
    // Services can only be injected inside the InvokeAsync method 
    public async Task InvokeAsync(
        HttpContext context,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IIdentityService identityService,
        ICacheService cacheService,
        IApplicationUserCustomerRepository applicationUserCustomerRepository)
    {
        context.User = (await context.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal!; 

        // Check if the request contains the session token
        var customerCodeHeader = context.Request.Headers["customer-code"].ToString();
        
        var noCustomerAttribute = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint?.Metadata
            .Any(m => m is NoCustomerCodeAttribute or AllowAnonymousAttribute) ?? false;
        
        if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Options.Method || noCustomerAttribute)
        {
            await next(context);
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerCodeHeader) || !int.TryParse(customerCodeHeader, out var customerCode))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return;
        }

        var user = await identityService.Get();

        if (user == null) 
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return;
        }

        MemoryCacheEntryOptions options = new();
        options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        var applicationUserCustomer =  await cacheService.GetAsync(
            cacheService.BuildCacheKey(nameof(ApplicationUserCustomer), user.ApplicationUserId.ToString(), customerCode.ToString()),
            () => applicationUserCustomerRepository.Get(x => x.ApplicationUserId == user.ApplicationUserId && x.CustomerCode == customerCode),
            options);
        
        if (applicationUserCustomer == null) 
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return;
        }
        
        await next(context); 
    } 
}

When running the line
context.User = (await context.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal!;

in the middleware, the principal is always returned correctly, but this should not be necessary. What am I missing here? I already tried moving all the app.Use() stuff around but I got nothing working yet.

With the order of your middleware, HttpContext.User is populated by the authentication middleware before your custom middleware(ApplicationUserCustomerValidationMiddleware) runs. By directly using context.User, you will have access to your user, also you can perform extra check. rewriting the middleware looks like this
public class ApplicationUserCustomerValidationMiddleware
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

  public ApplicationUserCustomerValidationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
  {
    _next = next;
  }

  public async Task InvokeAsync(
    HttpContext context,
    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
    IIdentityService identityService,
    ICacheService cacheService,
    IApplicationUserCustomerRepository applicationUserCustomerRepository)
 {
      var user = context.User;
      if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
          return;
      }

      var customerCodeHeader = context.Request.Headers["customer-code"].ToString();
      var noCustomerAttribute = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint?.Metadata
        .Any(m => m is NoCustomerCodeAttribute or AllowAnonymousAttribute) ?? false;

      if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Options.Method || noCustomerAttribute)
      {
          await _next(context);
          return;
      }

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerCodeHeader) || !int.TryParse(customerCodeHeader, out var customerCode))
      {
          context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
          return;
      }

      var applicationUser = await identityService.Get();

      if (applicationUser == null) 
      {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return;
      }

      MemoryCacheEntryOptions options = new();
    options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

      var applicationUserCustomer = await cacheService.GetAsync(
        cacheService.BuildCacheKey(nameof(ApplicationUserCustomer), applicationUser.ApplicationUserId.ToString(), customerCode.ToString()),
        () => applicationUserCustomerRepository.Get(x => x.ApplicationUserId == applicationUser.ApplicationUserId && x.CustomerCode == customerCode),
        options);

      if (applicationUserCustomer == null) 
      {
          context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
          return;
      }
    
      await _next(context); 
  } 
}


I am very confused, I guess some changed did fix my issue as now it seems like the context.User is filled in correctly. Will accept as answer, but for other people. My example above for order of Middleware is correct.

Your order is correct,
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
the two lines above would have already authenticated the user and set httpcontext.user value
